# Gradle sync error, Many things not resolved, AppCompactActivity not recognised as a class, only few external library shown

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, libraries

I have many problems with Android Studio 2.3, since the installation. I'll try to be as methodical as I can to explain all of them.

I- Material

I've a Laptop with Windows seven Ultimate x64 (not service pack 1, not any more recent version). 
CPU : AMD V140 2.30Ghz x 1
RAM : 3.00 Go
HDD : 500Go

I've installed Android Studio 2.3, given by a friend, but the software runs normally on his computer (core i5, windows seven sp1) . In the 'D:' disk. 
I've installed JDK1.8.0_141, and I've set his path as JDK_HOME
I've downloaded and properly (I hope) installed Android 7.1.1 (API 25), Android 4.4 (API 19) and Android 4.1 (API 16)

II. Android Studio
I've set the sdk directory

The problems are :
- When Gradle sync is completed, it shows

```
'failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12'
'failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
'failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
'failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
'failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
'failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3'
'failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1'
```

- On the design mode, activity_main.xml shows an empty rectangle and a blue rectangle, with this message

  ```
  'Preview timed out while rendering the layout. This typically happens when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views'
  ```
- The Java file of MainActivity only has the 11th first lines,  it stops and makes the }s at 'setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)'.
  This classes are written in red

  ```
  ('Cannot resolve symbol 'ClassName'') :

  AppCompactActivity, onCreate, setContentView, R.
  ```
- Using the Project view, I saw that I had only '< Android API 25 Platform >' as external library , then I exported the settings of my friend to import it to my computer, and now I also have < 1.8 >, constraint-layout-solver-1.0.0-alpha7, support-annotation-25.2.0. On his computer, they are a lot, and they are necessary.

III- Tries

- I've try to reinstall Android Studio
- I've try to create new projects
- I've try to add manually junit by copying it to the 'lib' folder of the project and setting it as a library,  but his still appears (not resolved)
- I've try uncheking Gradle's Offline work, I was connected to internet,  but the sync still has errors
- I've try to copy the settings from a computer where Android Studio has no worries.

Please, now I need your help. I want to know what to do, or just some things that I can also try. Thank you.

PS : I understand better French that English. Thanks for reading all this message

Comment: Did you reintall from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html ?

Comment: No, I reinstalled it with the same setup. I've also try online updating to Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: According to the requirements you are tight with RAM. But try doing a fresh install from the android developer site.

Comment: Seeing how many times I have reinstalled it, seeing that updating to the last version hasn't resolved the problem, seeing that the software installed with the same setup has functioned on another computer and seeing that I don't have 2Go of internet connection to restart downloading(I'm a young student), I can't try your solution, sorry.

Comment: I am really sorry to hear that. But even if you install Android Studio, it gets updates very frequently and, many times, these updates are huge.